# How to get store information (e.g Store Base Url) of another store in a multi-store setup for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, base-url

I have multiple stores on my Magento 2 installation. So I have store 1 base url as **http://mystore1.com** and store 2 base url as **http://mystore2.com**. How do i get the base url of store 2 dynamically on a phtml file in store 1.

**Note:** `$block->getBaseUrl()` will only return the current store url. Is there a function like `getBaseUrl` of store id = 2 ?

Comment: You tried `$block->getBaseUlr()` or `$this->getBaseUrl()` in your phtml?

Comment: if i use $block->getBaseUrl() while im on store 1 I will get http://mystore1.com. But that's not what I want. I need to get the store 2 url which is http://mystore2.com while im on store 1.

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your custom block, the below code will get the store Base Url by using store id:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Store extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getStoreUrl($storeId)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

In our custom phtml, we can call `$block->getStoreUrl($storeId);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
protected function generateForAllStores()
{
    $urls = [];
    foreach($this->storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
        $urls[] = $this->setUrlRewrite($store->getStoreId());
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Deexit, what classes do i need to extend or construct using this codes?

Comment: Yes @jjordao you can use  This interface in construct `code  - - Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`

Comment: Thanks @Deexit, your answer gives me more ideas to work on. Although Khoa's answer is more applicable in my situation right now. But great answer I will use this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

In `phtml` file you can call base url with the help of store id :

```
$block->getStoreUrl($store_id);
```